# can't create javaScript algorithm for access function

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have some tabs in my app, like reports, tasks and so on ...
Also users have different permissions like reports.add, tasks.delete.
I need to create function to check what user is allowed to do.

```
// for example array with all current user permissions
// this permissions mean user is allowed to do everything with tasks
// add and edit reports, but not allowed to to delete it

const permissions = ['reports.add', 'reports.edit', 'tasks'];

const isAllowed = (condition) => {
   return permissions.some((permission) => {
            // here is problem, I can't create algorithm
       });
};


// When user clicks delete report button 
// I expect to use this function like this 

if (isAllowed('reports.delete')) {
    deleteReport()
}
```

Comment: why you dont create a normal function? it is easier, readable and reusable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could search in `permissions` if `condition` starts with a `permission`.

```js
const
    permissions = ['reports.add', 'reports.edit', 'tasks'],
    isAllowed = condition => permissions.some(permission => condition.startsWith(permission));

console.log(isAllowed('reports.add')); //  true
console.log(isAllowed('tasks.edit'));  //  true
console.log(isAllowed('tasks'));       //  true
console.log(isAllowed('task'));        // false
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it wouldn't work for me. Because value 'tasks' in permissions, it means user is allowed to do everything with tasks, edit, delete and add tasks. isAllowed('tasks.edit') should return true if 'tasks'  in permissions.

Comment: Expand this answer to include: const isAllowed = condition => permissions.includes(condition.split('.')[0]) || permissions.includes(condition);

Comment: Thank you guys, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you can just create a normal function and avoid an anonymous function inside another...

```
function isAllowed(permission) {
    return condition; //or some if-else
}
```